# ggplot plotting hourly stock price does not ignore the weekend effect

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

here's some typical hourly stock OHLCV data (a `tibble` in R, showing only the first 100 rows), I call it `stock`:

```
     Open   High    Low  Close      Volume date                   
     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl> <dttm>                 
  1 224.22 225.04 223.35 224.21  7960000.   2017-07-03 13:00:00.000
  2 224.22 228.03 224.22 227.94 15000000    2017-07-03 14:00:00.000
  3 227.86 229.02 226.99 228.18 14740000.   2017-07-03 15:00:00.000
  4 228.18 228.45 226.88 227.31 14480000.   2017-07-03 16:00:00.000
  5 227.31 227.31 227.31 227.31    10000.00 2017-07-03 17:00:00.000
  6 228.38 228.76 225.83 226.27  9060000.   2017-07-05 13:00:00.000
  7 226.14 227.26 225.2  227.17 15450000.   2017-07-05 14:00:00.000
  8 227.17 227.77 226.68 227.27 11550000.   2017-07-05 15:00:00.000
  9 227.25 227.75 226.71 227.75  8070000.   2017-07-05 16:00:00.000
 10 227.76 228.07 227.61 227.83  8620000.   2017-07-05 17:00:00.000
 11 227.81 228.15 227.41 227.59 10080000.   2017-07-05 18:00:00.000
 12 227.61 228.25 227.3  227.95 13440000.   2017-07-05 19:00:00.000
 13 227.74 228.32 225.22 225.69  7350000.   2017-07-06 13:00:00.000
 14 225.7  227.53 225.38 227.03 11680000.   2017-07-06 14:00:00.000
 15 227.07 227.75 226.74 227.56 10450000.   2017-07-06 15:00:00.000
 16 227.55 228.52 227.47 228.49  9290000.   2017-07-06 16:00:00.000
 17 228.47 230.01 228.47 228.52 13910000.   2017-07-06 17:00:00.000
 18 228.49 228.61 227.1  227.47 12660000.   2017-07-06 18:00:00.000
 19 227.41 227.6  226.36 226.6  15660000.   2017-07-06 19:00:00.000
 20 228.13 228.31 226.59 226.67  7780000.   2017-07-07 13:00:00.000
 21 226.7  226.93 225.05 225.17 11550000.   2017-07-07 14:00:00.000
 22 225.17 226.33 225.17 225.97 10400000.   2017-07-07 15:00:00.000
 23 226.03 226.76 225.83 226.07  8780000.   2017-07-07 16:00:00.000
 24 226.07 226.29 225.5  225.78  6400000.   2017-07-07 17:00:00.000
 25 225.79 225.9  225.09 225.09  7230000.   2017-07-07 18:00:00.000
 26 225.09 225.26 224.41 225.21 11190000.   2017-07-07 19:00:00.000
 27 224    226.64 223.89 226.58  7710000.   2017-07-10 13:00:00.000
 28 226.58 227.2  225.19 226.12 11040000.   2017-07-10 14:00:00.000
 29 226.15 226.15 225.09 225.59  8810000.   2017-07-10 15:00:00.000
 30 225.59 227.2  225.59 227.2  10480000.   2017-07-10 16:00:00.000
 31 227.21 227.21 226.14 226.5   8780000.   2017-07-10 17:00:00.000
 32 226.51 226.59 225.88 226.08  8170000.   2017-07-10 18:00:00.000
 33 226.08 226.28 225.44 225.83 12900000.   2017-07-10 19:00:00.000
 34 226.09 226.68 225.74 225.88  6120000.   2017-07-11 13:00:00.000
 35 225.92 227.03 224.9  227.02 12230000.   2017-07-11 14:00:00.000
 36 227.04 227.26 224.62 226.85 13290000.   2017-07-11 15:00:00.000
 37 226.85 227.34 226.3  227.31 10730000.   2017-07-11 16:00:00.000
 38 227.28 227.91 226.93 227.81 11050000.   2017-07-11 17:00:00.000
 39 227.81 227.87 226.86 227.32  8870000.   2017-07-11 18:00:00.000
 40 227.31 227.55 226.95 227.02 12200000.   2017-07-11 19:00:00.000
 41 226.46 228.4  226    227.79  8270000.   2017-07-12 13:00:00.000
 42 227.75 228.92 227.75 228.14 13740000.   2017-07-12 14:00:00.000
 43 228.12 228.84 228    228.61 10210000.   2017-07-12 15:00:00.000
 44 228.63 228.64 226.75 227.19  9520000.   2017-07-12 16:00:00.000
 45 227.19 227.71 227.19 227.55  7620000.   2017-07-12 17:00:00.000
 46 227.47 227.83 227.25 227.72  8510000.   2017-07-12 18:00:00.000
 47 227.71 227.71 227.07 227.32 14220000.   2017-07-12 19:00:00.000
 48 226.95 228.7  226.8  228.32  8070000.   2017-07-13 13:00:00.000
 49 228.34 229.87 227.96 229.64 15470000.   2017-07-13 14:00:00.000
 50 229.63 229.99 229.05 229.88 10170000.   2017-07-13 15:00:00.000
 51 229.86 229.91 229.25 229.56  8090000.   2017-07-13 16:00:00.000
 52 229.6  229.85 229.2  229.25  9040000.   2017-07-13 17:00:00.000
 53 229.26 229.79 229.14 229.7   8260000.   2017-07-13 18:00:00.000
 54 229.7  230.59 229.42 230.53 13660000.   2017-07-13 19:00:00.000
 55 227.2  228.55 225    228.55  9580000.   2017-07-14 13:00:00.000
 56 228.55 228.59 226.92 227.92 14670000.   2017-07-14 14:00:00.000
 57 227.93 228.71 227.77 228.56 10210000.   2017-07-14 15:00:00.000
 58 228.54 228.82 227.88 228.62  8850000.   2017-07-14 16:00:00.000
 59 228.64 229.47 228.38 228.61 10310000.   2017-07-14 17:00:00.000
 60 228.61 228.91 228.14 228.89  7620000.   2017-07-14 18:00:00.000
 61 228.89 229.59 228.68 228.84 14460000.   2017-07-14 19:00:00.000
 62 228.52 228.57 227.13 228.1   7150000.   2017-07-17 13:00:00.000
 63 228.06 228.8  227.78 228.75 13040000.   2017-07-17 14:00:00.000
 64 228.77 229.27 228.27 229.14 11010000.   2017-07-17 15:00:00.000
 65 229.1  229.39 228.76 228.9   9240000.   2017-07-17 16:00:00.000
 66 228.9  229.52 228.64 229.04  9940000.   2017-07-17 17:00:00.000
 67 229.05 229.6  228.72 229.22  9910000.   2017-07-17 18:00:00.000
 68 229.22 229.38 228.57 229.14 13740000.   2017-07-17 19:00:00.000
 69 227.06 230.14 226.2  227.27 10190000.   2017-07-18 13:00:00.000
 70 227.27 227.68 222.74 224.4  17559999.   2017-07-18 14:00:00.000
 71 224.41 224.43 223.12 223.47 12790000.   2017-07-18 15:00:00.000
 72 223.5  223.92 223.01 223.44  8720000.   2017-07-18 16:00:00.000
 73 223.46 224.86 223.42 223.63  9910000.   2017-07-18 17:00:00.000
 74 223.61 224.43 223.33 223.9  10150000.   2017-07-18 18:00:00.000
 75 223.91 224.03 222.88 223.22 13100000.   2017-07-18 19:00:00.000
 76 222.86 223.6  221.9  222.27 10030000.   2017-07-19 13:00:00.000
 77 222.2  224.12 221.76 223.1  15850000.   2017-07-19 14:00:00.000
 78 223.11 223.86 222.73 222.79  9680000.   2017-07-19 15:00:00.000
 79 222.8  223    221.66 221.74 10550000.   2017-07-19 16:00:00.000
 80 221.74 222.54 221.68 222.17  8640000.   2017-07-19 17:00:00.000
 81 222.17 222.69 221.92 222.67  8330000.   2017-07-19 18:00:00.000
 82 222.65 223.24 222.49 222.92 11170000.   2017-07-19 19:00:00.000
 83 222.94 224.02 222.85 223.87  8000000    2017-07-20 13:00:00.000
 84 223.92 224.74 223.04 223.79 16379999.   2017-07-20 14:00:00.000
 85 223.79 224.07 222.47 222.86 11850000.   2017-07-20 15:00:00.000
 86 222.85 222.85 222.06 222.27  9000000    2017-07-20 16:00:00.000
 87 222.27 222.48 221.61 222.1   9400000.   2017-07-20 17:00:00.000
 88 222.08 222.8  221.88 222.45  9580000.   2017-07-20 18:00:00.000
 89 222.49 223.01 222.2  222.27 11200000.   2017-07-20 19:00:00.000
 90 222.3  222.3  222.3  222.3     10000.00 2017-07-20 20:00:00.000
 91 221.44 222.28 219.71 219.87  8800000.   2017-07-21 13:00:00.000
 92 219.87 220.63 219.09 219.95 15470000.   2017-07-21 14:00:00.000
 93 219.98 220.3  219.7  220.02 11170000.   2017-07-21 15:00:00.000
 94 220.02 220.41 219.81 220.38  8790000.   2017-07-21 16:00:00.000
 95 220.35 220.96 220.25 220.87  8400000.   2017-07-21 17:00:00.000
 96 220.87 220.9  220.12 220.26  8340000.   2017-07-21 18:00:00.000
 97 220.26 220.52 219.8  220.41 11510000.   2017-07-21 19:00:00.000
 98 218.77 219.59 218    218.74  7740000.   2017-07-24 13:00:00.000
 99 218.75 219.42 218.02 219.09 13790000.   2017-07-24 14:00:00.000
100 219.1  219.16 218.62 218.84 11840000.   2017-07-24 15:00:00.000
```

One way in ggplot to render data above can be:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot)

stock %>% ggplot(aes(x=date, y=Close)) + geom_path()
```

and it is plotted below:

[image]

It is not very hard to notice the uncomfortable zigzagging, which was caused by the regular trading hours having only 7.5 hours a day and the rest were simply treated as no data.

How to tell `ggplot` to ignore these hours of no trading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without having gaps in the plot, though it is not straightforward because your x axis is now no longer a continuous variable.

The way to achieve it is to use a sequence of integers as the values on the x axis but change the *labels* of the x axis according to the associated date. You could therefore do something like this:

```r
stock %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = 1:nrow(stock), y = Close)) + 
  geom_path() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 25, 50, 75, 100),
                     labels = format(stock$date[c(1, 25, 50, 75, 100)], "%d %b %Y")
   ) +
  labs(x = "Date") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this is interesting, not sure how `ggplot` knows to take out the gaps when we convert it discrete but this how I wanted it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wday` function from the`lubridate` package to filter out rows that occur on Saturdays and Sundays:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

n <- 10000
df <- data.frame(
  dt = Sys.time() + 300*(1:n),
  price = cumsum(rnorm(n))
) %>%
  mutate(weekend = wday(dt) %in% 6:7)
```

Once you filter out these rows, you can add the `group` aesthetic as the `week` of the price to make sure the lines don't continue over the weekend. Note that the default for `week` is to count weeks starting January 1, so I shift it a few days to align with weekends:

```
df %>%
  filter(!weekend) %>%
  ggplot(aes(dt, price, group = week(dt-48*60*60))) +
  geom_path() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I wanted to take out the gaps so the series looks continuous.  Allan's answer is how I wanted it.